# migrating data from mysql to postgres pgloader IRONCLAD::SIMPLE-OCTET-VECTOR

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I am migrating data from MySQL to Postgres using pgloader.
My script works fine on my local machine. But as I am running pgloader to prod database it's giving me following error

`The value of SEQUENCE is "?;JAExN[^F#yZ:O_o3Mj...", which is not of type IRONCLAD::SIMPLE-OCTET-VECTOR.`

I have tried the following way .
https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782.

database is hosted on azure

I am not sure what went wrong. 
Any help is appreciated